# nokia j2me fullscreen width, height are not returned after setting it

Tags: java-me, fullscreen, nokia, midp, lcdui

I'm creating a canvas and setting it as fullscreen. In the canvas my getHeight() and getWidth() functions does not return the actual height and width of the full screen. It returns them as if I didn't set it to full screen.

How can I get the size of the full screen in nokia phones or other ones that have the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

What a nokia phone do you use? How do you set it to fullscreen? I used some nokia S60, S40, and it works.

This may be help for someone:

```
public MainCanvas(KeyDetection midlet, Display display) {
    setFullScreenMode(true);
    this.midlet = midlet;
    this.display = display;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a small delay between calling 'setFullScreenMode(true)' and for canvas actually going to full screen mode. Adding a small delay (~500ms) after the call to go full screen should do the trick